# Is male DVI-d male DVI-i ends compatible

Tags: dvi, av-cable

My video card has a DVI-I connector and my monitor has a DVI-D. The problem is I can't find a connector with male DVI-I and male DVI-D? I've searched amazon and newegg but can't find one. If i buy a cable that's male DVI-d/DVI-d will it work if i plug a male DVI-d male connector into my DVI-i female port on my video card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a DVI-D cable. The DVI-D connector fits into a DVI-I port (not the other way round, though), the added pins on the -I connector are used for the analogue signal.

[image: DVI-D Connector Types]

Comment: So I won't lose any video quality on my monitor if I use a male DVI-D cable into the DVI-I female port? But i can't reverse it? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you won't lose any video quality using just a DVI-D cable - it's a purely digital link. DVI-I additionally offers an analogue connection that your screen won't use (as it's DVI-D only).

Answer (score 1):

DVI-I is like DVI-D and DVI-A merged together, it can be used both for digital (DVI-D) and analog (DVI-A) signal. Your video card has DVI-I output, which means it can transmit both analog and digital. It's sending the same image, but encoded in two ways. You want *at least one* of those signals to be connected to your monitor.

Your monitor has DVI-D port, so it can receive digital signal only. You can safely use a DVI-D cable. Nothing will be lost, because your monitor doesn't support analog input (and there's no need to provide the same image encoded as analog anyway).